# only name in dropdown

Tags: linq, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I try to fill dropdown value
in table column  values are

```
KHI
ISL
LAHR
PARIS
LONDON
BCE-456
BXR-445
BET-567
TYU-112
OPL-456
```

NOW I dont want these

```
BXR-445
BET-567
TYU-112
OPL-456 etc etc
```

i want only city names not numbers

i try to populate throug this

```
 var list = tea.tblRe.AsEnumerable()
                   .Where(x => !x.Region.Any(char.IsDigit))
                    .ToList();
```

so when i try above query this show only names but with repepation like this e.g.

```
   KHI
   ISL
   KHI
   LONDON
   LONDON
   LAHR
   ISL
   ISL
   ISL
   PARIS
   LONDON
   PARIS
   PARIS
```

**UPDATE**

ok for this i i try to implement 'IEqualityComparer'

```
class tablregionclass : IEqualityComparer<tblRe>
{
    #region IEqualityComparer<tblRe> Members

    public bool Equals(tblRe x, tblRe y)
    {
        return x.Region.Equals(y.Region);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(tblRe obj)
    {
        return obj.Region.GetHashCode();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

and then when i implment this class like this

```
 IEqualityComparer<tblRe_New> customComparer = new tablregionclass();
            IEnumerable<tblRe_New> disntregions = collection.Distinct(customComparer);
```

this show error

```
Error   2   The name 'collection' does not exist in the current context 
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'chart_project.tablregionclass' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<chart_project.tblReg_New>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Comment: What are the values that you want to omit? Why are they stored in the same column? What is the column you want to select at all?

Comment: these all are in one column this column name is region.. and i want omit values when they have number chaharacter

Comment: you need to add `using System.Collections.Generic`

Comment: @LucianBumb PLEASE CHECK UPDATE

Comment: the error msgs are self explanatory, What is collection? and you cannot cast object A in object B. Did you try the last query which I put in my answer, the one which result in a list of Anonymous objects?

Comment: ok thanku but please will you please this line .Select(x=>new {Region=x.Key, Value=x.Key})

Comment: @LucianBumb and also if i wan to add another condition in where like if there is any value which is empty in region column then how to set condition like this  && !(Region.Region == "")

Comment: before group by you can put as many where conditions you want

Comment: ok please explain this line .Select(x=>new {Region=x.Key, Value=x.Key})

Comment: a group has a key and an object, after grouping the list<obj> base on Region, results a list of groups with the key=Region. From this list I selected an object without name (anonymous) which contain 2 props: Region and Value, props which you can bind to the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `char.IsDigit` and `Distinct`(instead of `GroupBy`)

```
var res = tea.tblRegion_Uni.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x => !x.Region.Any(char.IsDigit))
    .Select(x=> x.Region)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

if you need to bind to list of objects, then:

```
var res = tea.tblRegion_Uni.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x => !x.Region.Any(char.IsDigit))
    .ToList();
```

I removed the select statment and Distinct!

For `Distinct` to work, you need to implement `IEqualityComparer`, or you can try this:

```
 var res = tea.tblRegion_Uni.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(x => !x.Region.Any(char.IsDigit))
        .GroupBy(x=>x.Region)
        .Select(x=>new {Region=x.Key, Value=x.Key})
        .ToList();
```

Here I am returning an anonymous object with 2 props.

Comment: When i try this show error An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'Region'.

Comment: on  regiondrop.DataBind();

Comment: the result of the query is a list of strings!, if you want a list of ojects, remove the select from query!

Comment: if you call `Distinct()` method on your list will not work, to make it work you need to implement `IEqualityComparer` in your model class. There are a lots of question how to implement this interface

Comment: check please update question i try to implement IEqualityComparer class but this show error

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match which have a number, use RegExp:

```
var pattern = \[0-9]\g;
alert(pattern.test("BCE-456"));
```